# OpenCV-Python cv2.videocapture window shrinks

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to get a simple opencv-python video capture to work which shows the live stream of the camera. However, when I run the code the camera window frame opens up and then immediately shrinks into a tiny line. here is a picture to show:

[image]

In the top right hand corner is a white line which should be the frame window.

I have tried installing the V4L2 driver and the red light comes on on the pi cam but I am not able to view through the window.

Comment: I think you need `cv2.imshow('frame',frame)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to change imshow to

> cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

The first argument is just the title of the window.